# CSS Ribbon - controlling the width of the sides

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

```
.ribbon {
  width: 288px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 123px;
  left: 250px;
  background: #000;
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 30px solid #333333;
  z-index: -1;
}
.ribbon:before {
  left: -33px;
  top: -10px;
  border-left-width: 15px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
.ribbon:after {
  right: -33px;
  bottom: -10px;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}
```

.. but I can't quite control the width of the sides to make it look like this:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that there is space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with `border-right-width` on `::before` and `border-left-width:` on `::after`. At least, it works in that pen when I do that.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wHCeA

Pen demonstrating.

Comment: I.e. just reduce the width of right/left border of the sides. From `30px` to whatsoever.